pc runs slow and cpu stays constant
i have windows 10 and cpu always remains constant and spu usage doesn't increase or decrease no matter what I use and all the resources are underutilised.as you can see in image CPU usage is in straight line.
Please help me to figure out the problem


Is this a laptop? If is, any issues on battery or not original psu(adapter)?

0.48 GHz suggests the CPU is severely affected by thermal throttling as that’s only 480 MHz. The base clock of your processor isn’t 480 MHz.

In Power Options -> Change plans settings -> Change advanced settings, look at Processor power management -> Maximum processor state.

@Danijel soryy this is my laptop and yes there is issue in my battery......

@Ramhound is there any solution to solve this issue.....

@DrMoishePippik setting is already in Maximum processor state

Issue is with laptop firmware, you need to disable "BD PROCHOT"(if i remember right), this is also a "protection" for both you and laptop from purchasing something that IE Acer did not made for your laptop. I resolved this by using https://www.techpowerup.com/download/techpowerup-throttlestop/ but be careful as it can fry your lap if mismanaged and please inform yourself a bit more before using it.
